My brebo smtp is not to setup and i did not get msg i did not get runing code problem and pass will be right
there is client section  use next js and typscrip input  data also use react hook from but i not get data
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import * as z from "zod";

import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

import {
    Select,
    SelectContent,
    SelectItem,
    SelectTrigger,
    SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormDescription,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";

import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";

import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";

import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { PiCheckLight, PiSmiley } from "react-icons/pi";
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";

const FormSchema = z.object({
    first_name: z.string(),
    last_name: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    job_title: z.string(),
    company_name: z.string(),
    help: z.enum([
        "Evaluate CodeSeo for my company",
        "Learn More",
        "Get a Quote",
        "Other",
    ]),
    services: z.enum([
        "UI/UX Design",
        "Local buisness SEO",
        "Graphic Design",
        "Website Design",
        "Website Development",
    ]),
    info: z.string(),
});

type FormValues = {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    job_title: string;
    company_name: string;
    help:
        | "Evaluate CodeSeo for my company"
        | "Learn More"
        | "Get a Quote"
        | "Other";
    services:
        | "UI/UX Design"
        | "Local buisness SEO"
        | "Graphic Design"
        | "Website Design"
        | "Website Development";
    info: string;
    terms: boolean;
};

export default function ContactForm() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const { toast } = useToast();

    const form = useForm<FormValues>({
        resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            first_name: "",
            last_name: "",
            email: "",
            job_title: "",
            company_name: "",
            help: "Learn More",
            services: "Local buisness SEO",
            info: "",
        },
    });

    async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const res = await fetch("/api/contact", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("Something went wrong");
            }

            setSubmitted(true);
        } catch (error) {
            toast({
                title: "Error",
                description: "Something went wrong",
            });
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className=" w-full   md:items-center md:justify-center bg-black/[0.96] antialiased bg-grid-white/[0.02] relative overflow-hidden ">
            <Navbar
                scrollToWebsiteDesign={() => {}}
                scrollToGraphicDesign={() => {}}
                scrollToShopifyStores={() => {}}
                scrollToBrands={() => {}}
                scrollToServices={() => {}}
                contact={false}
            />
            <div className="md:flex items-start justify-center md:py-20 px-6">
                <div className="">
                    <div className="text-5xl font-medium  w-full md:w-2/3  pb-5 md:text-7xl bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                        Contact our sales team
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className="
              
              py-4
              text-gray-300
                    "
                    >
                        Let&apos;s talk about how CodeSeo can help your team work better.
                    </div>

                    <div className="bg-[#f6f5f4] md:w-4/5 space-y-6 p-4 rounded-2xl my-4 hidden md:flex md:flex-col">
                        <div className="flex gap-4 border-b ">
                            <div className=" font-normal pb-4 ">
                                One flexible agency for your entire company to share knowledge,
                                ship projects, and collaborate.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="flex gap-4 border-b ">
                            <div className=" font-normal pb-4 ">
                                Enterprise features to securely manage user access and security.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="flex gap-4  ">
                            <div className=" font-normal pb-4 ">
                                Dedicated support to work with you on your setup and help you
                                build the best plan for your company.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Form {...form}>
                    {!submitted ? (
                        <form
                            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                            className="
            space-y-4
            h-full
            border rounded-3xl p-10
            md:w-1/3                     
                        "
                        >
                            <div className="md:flex items-center gap-6 ">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="first_name"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="items-center justify-center  w-full">
                                            <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                                First name *
                                            </FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input {...field} />
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="last_name"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="items-center justify-center  w-full">
                                            <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                                Last name *
                                            </FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input {...field} />
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="email"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="items-center justify-center  w-full">
                                        <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                            Email *
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input {...field} />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="company_name"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="items-center justify-center  w-full">
                                        <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                            Company name?
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input {...field} />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="services"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="items-center justify-center w-full">
                                        <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                            Services you are interested in
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                            defaultValue={field.value}
                                        >
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <SelectTrigger>
                                                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select an option" />
                                                </SelectTrigger>
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <SelectContent>
                                                <div className="flex gap-4">
                                                    <SelectItem value="Local buisness SEO">
                                                        Local buisness SEO
                                                    </SelectItem>
                                                </div>
                                                <SelectItem value="Graphic Design">
                                                    Graphic Design
                                                </SelectItem>
                                                <SelectItem value="UI/UX Design">
                                                    UI/Ux Design
                                                </SelectItem>
                                                <SelectItem value="Web Development">
                                                    Web Development
                                                </SelectItem>
                                                <SelectItem value="Website Design">
                                                    Websit Design
                                                </SelectItem>
                                            </SelectContent>
                                        </Select>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="help"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="items-center justify-center  w-full">
                                        <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                            How can we help ?
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                            defaultValue={field.value}
                                        >
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <SelectTrigger>
                                                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select an option" />
                                                </SelectTrigger>
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <SelectContent>
                                                <div className="flex gap-4">
                                                    <SelectItem value="Evaluate CodeSeo for my company">
                                                        Evaluate CodeSeo for my company
                                                    </SelectItem>
                                                </div>
                                                <SelectItem value="Learn More">Learn More</SelectItem>
                                                <SelectItem value="Get a Quote">Get a Quote</SelectItem>
                                                <SelectItem value="Get a Quote">Site Audit</SelectItem>

                                                <SelectItem value="Other">Other</SelectItem>
                                            </SelectContent>
                                        </Select>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="info"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className="items-center justify-center w-full">
                                        <FormLabel className="text-sm bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400 bg-opacity-50">
                                            Anything else ?
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Textarea style={{ height: "100px" }} {...field} />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <div className="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        className="
                outline
                border-2
                text-sm
                font-light
                bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400
                "
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="text-xs font-light  md:w-3/4 mb-1 bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral-50 to-neutral-400">
                                    I agree to CodeSeo&apos; sending marketing communications
                                    related to CodeSeo
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="
                            text-sm
                            font-light
                        
                            "
                                    disabled={loading}
                                    onClick={() => form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                                >
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <div
                                className="
        text-xl 
        
        md:text-2xl 
        flex 
        items-center
        justify-center
        flex-col
        

 
        px-8

        "
                            >
                                <div className="w-80 py-20">
                                    <PiSmiley className="text-6xl text-[#6c6684] mx-auto" />

                                    <div className="text-gray-500 font-light  text-center justify-center mx-auto py-10">
                                        We&apos;ve received your inquiry and will be contacting you
                                        via email shortly.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


this is my smtp setup at brebo but it not working i want work it
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        try {
            const {
                first_name = "Not provided",
                last_name = "Not provided",
                email = "Not provided",
                job_title = "Not provided",
                company_name = "Not provided",
                website_name = "Not provided",
                help = "Not provided",
                services = "Not provided",
                info = "Not provided",
            } = await req.json();

            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: "smtp-relay.brevo.com",
                port: 587,
                secure: true,
                auth: {
                    user: "ibrahimkhalilullah534@gmail.com",
                    pass: "hide for previcy perpose",
                },
            });

            const mailOptions = {
                from: email,
                to: "ibrahimkhalilullah534@gmail.com",
                subject: "Contact Form Submission",
                html: `
                    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
                    <p>First Name: ${first_name}</p>
                    <p>Last Name: ${last_name}</p>
                    <p>Last Name: ${job_title}</p>
                    <p>Last Name: ${services}</p>
                    <p>Work Email: ${email}</p>
                    <p>Company Name: ${company_name}</p>
                    <p>Company Name: ${website_name}</p>               
                    <p>Help: ${help}</p>           
                    <p>Info: ${info}</p>
                `,
            };

            await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

            return NextResponse.json("email has been sent");
        } catch (error) {
            return NextResponse.json("email has not been sent");
        }
    } else {
        return NextResponse.json("method not allowed");
    }
}


how to solve  code is run
here is contact page code i mean page.tsx
and under code is brevo smtp use those pass not use my real password i used what they provide me master password ,this code go to my ap folder to contact rout.ts here under i
give what is backend code run but  when i test i did not get msage
her is documentation  tobrebo typscript use https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-typescript-library
